# Deleting a Non-existing file

Tags: linux, windows, file

First things first:

- I have a windows OS.
- I use python in Linux (from a USB stick)
- I was writing a code in Python that required it to work with Excel...

so once I created it (in Linux) I got a `xlwt` file created in the `D:` drive of my computer.
when I booted into windows I wanted to delete the file but it says

```
The file you specified is not valid or is too long
```

so I tried deleting it in command prompt(admin) but it says file does not exist!
when I type `dir` the file gets displayed 
so I went in Linux(Kali Linux) and tried

```
rm -f xlwt
```

but same problem:

when I say `dir` in Linux it says `xlwt\r`

so I said

```
rm -f xlwt\r
```

but still the same problem.

Comment: Do you want a pythonic solution?

Comment: in linux, try using `rm` followed by the first few characters of your filename,  then hit `<tab>` it should complete the file and escape the newline character such that pressing `<enter>` will properly remove it

Comment: If that doesn't work, there are several possible solutions here: https://www.linux.com/blog/linux-shell-tip-remove-files-names-contains-spaces-and-special-characters-such

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: I guess this is a gray area, but I don't think it is off-topic, because it is a class of problem that only programmers commonly run into.  (Well, on Windows at any rate.  I don't know about Linux.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux use tab completion to get the correct escaped version of the file name.

Type the following:

```
rm xlw
```

Then press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key and the shell will complete the filename with the right escape chars for the '/r'

You should then be able to press enter to delete the file